# Can UEFI Secure Boot be achieved on Macs prior to T2 secure chip?

Tags: startup, security

A little bit more detail, what i'm curious about is if a Mac's firmware can be set up to validate a EFI binary's attached signature against a cert that's stored in the EFI variables by user.

If so, how does Mac toggle between normal mode and set up mode? (as in allowing/forbidding the certs in EFI variables to be modified)

The scenario i have in mind is to have a recent Intel Mac right before the T2 chip got added, say the Haswell generation around 2014 and 2015, and i hope to have the Mac's firmware to validate the integrity of the grub efi binary before booting it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple only officially supports macOS and Windows for use on Macs. Therefore, the firmware does not support Secure Boot. A Mac with a T2 chip can be configured to only allow booting of macOS and Windows 10. A Mac's firmware can not validate the integrity of a grub efi binary. Having T2 chip does not change this.

As for a setup mode, basically a Mac with a T2 has the following window.

[image]

The instructions for configuring can be found at the Apple website [About Startup Security Utility](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208198).